# Rudin's real and complex analysis chapter 1 #10

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $\mu(X)<\infty$, $\{f_n\}$ is a sequence of bounded complex measurable functions on $X$, and $f_n \to f$ uniformly on $X$. Prove that $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_X f_n d\mu =\int_X f d\mu.$$

Is the condition of uniform convergence necessary? If it is, is it because $f_n$ are complex valued functions? (I haven't had complex analysis yet.)

I think if $\{f_n\}$ is bounded, then we can find a $g$ such that $|f_n|<g$. Since $g$ can be a constant function, $g\in L^1(\mu)$. Then by Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem, we can get the result.

Comment: Hint: On $X=(0,1)$ with Lebesgue measure $\mu,$ consider $f_n(t) = nt^n.$

Comment: @zhw. Sorry. I can't understand what's your point.

Comment: The question is assuming that each $f_n$ is bounded (i.e. for each $n$, there is $M_n$, such that $\lvert f_n \rvert \le M_n$), but not that the sequence is uniformly bounded (i.e., there is $M$ such that $\lvert f_n \rvert \le M$ for all $n$). If the sequence was uniformly bounded, then yes, you could use the dominated convergence theorem as you've said. The fact that $f_n$ are complex valued is basically irrelevant - it's not the crux of the problem.

Comment: @user398843 The $f_n$ in my example are bounded and converge pointwise to $0$ on $(0,1),$ but $\int_0^1f_n \to 1.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $a_n:= \sup \{|f_n(x)-f(x)|: x \in X\}$. Then $a_n \to 0$ and

$|\int_X f_n d \mu - \int_X f d \mu|  \le \int_X |f_n  -f| d \mu \le\int_X a_n d \mu =a_n \mu(X)$.

Comment: Thank you for the nice proof. I think $a_n:= \sup \{|f_n(x)-f(x)|: x \in X\} \implies a_n\to0$ only requires $f_n$ pointwise converges to $f$. So the statement can be weaken to pointwise convergence?

Comment: No. $a_n \to 0$ is equivalent with $(f_n)$ converges uniformly to $f$. Let $X=(0,1)$ and $f_n(x)=x^n$. Then $(f_n)$ converges pointwise to $0$ on $X$, but not uniformly, since $a_n=1$ for all $n$.